# C# Quick PictureBox image and Resource image comparsion

Tags: c#, image, resources, comparison, picturebox

I've been dealing with this problem for way too long. I wanted to compare, if the PictureBox has the same image as the one in the Resources, so naturally I went like this;

```
if(picturebox1.Image==Properties.Resources.image1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!"):
}
```

But it didn't work. So, I tried differently;

```
if(picturebox1.Image.Equals(Properties.Resources.image1))
```

That also didn't work. I tried with Bitmap;

```
Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.image1);
if(temp==Properties.Resources.image1)
```

It also didn't work. I searched the internet (including StackOverflow) and all the answers were like 50 lines long. Is there **really** no simple way to compare a PictureBox image with a Resource image?!

Comment: Another option is to store what image is being displayed in some other way.  You could place a string or integer, or an enum value, into the [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the PictureBox.

Comment: Oh my dearest, you're right @Idle_Mind ! When I compare Tags of those images it actually works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his comment @Idle_Mind suggested using [Tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare images, and it seems to be the easiest way to do it! Thanks again for your help!